# PivotTable for questionnaire analysis

Tags: excel, pivot-table, unpivot

I have some data from a reply form that I need to compile. I have some questions that have values from 1-5 or No-Yes. Example data:

```
Date       Question1 Question2 Question3
2010-12-01      4       3       No
2010-12-01      5       5       No
2010-12-01      4       3       Yes
2010-12-01      4       4       Yes
2010-12-01      3       4       No
2010-12-01      3       4       No
2010-12-01      2       4       Yes
2010-12-01      2       3       Yes
2010-12-01      2       4       Yes
2011-01-01      4       3       No
2011-01-01      5       1       No
2011-01-01      3       5       No
2011-01-01      5       4       No
2011-01-01      4       3       No
2011-01-01      3       4       No
2011-01-01      4       4       No
2011-01-01      5       4       No
2011-01-01      5       4       No
2011-01-01      3       3       No
2011-01-01      4       4       No
2011-01-01      3       5       Yes
2011-02-01      3       4       No
2011-02-01      5       5       No
2011-02-01      4       3       No
2011-02-01      4       5       No
2011-02-01      4       3       Yes
2011-02-01      4       5       No
2011-02-01      2       3       No
2011-02-01      2       5       No
```

I want to make a pivot table that I can use to analyse my data. I would like that it's like:

```
<whatever>     1 2 3 4 5
2010-12-01     
-Question1     0 3 2 3 1  
-Question2     0 0 3 5 1
2011-01-01     
-Question1     0 0 4 4 4  
-Question2     1 0 3 6 2
2011-01-01     
-Question1     0 2 1 4 1  
-Question2     0 0 3 1 4
```

Or an even smarter pivot table for analysing, but has to be organized by date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpivot (eg as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20543651/1505120)), sort the Table on Column to move `Question3` to the bottom. Convert to Range and pivot data down to the end of `Question2` with Row above Column for ROWS, Value for COLUMNS and Count of Value for VALUES.

Add a row above the PT and filter the left-hand column to select greater than `0`. Format the values to blend into the background. In PivotTable Options, enter `0`For empty cells show: . Result should be  something like (month does not match for the bottom set):

[image: O28413421 example]

Answer (score 0):

Best solution I found was not a PivotTable. It was most readable when I used merged cells insted.

[image]